# What's missing from this code?

Tags: jquery, css, function, animation, onclick

I'm trying to make the green circle alternate between red and green when clicked. The code looks fine to me but it's not working so something must be wrong. What beginner mistake am I making?

```js
$("#greenCircle").click(function() {
  console.log($("#greenCircle").css("background-color"));
  if ($("#greenCircle").css("background-color") == "red") {
    $("#greenCircle").css("background-color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#greenCircle").css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

```css
#greenCircle {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenCircle"></div>
```

I'm going absolutely insane! I'm just doing a simple jQuery animation and again it's just not working. Everything looks correct. I even went as far as switching text editors and nothing. Here's the code for the animation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JQuery</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery Practice.css">

</head>
<body>
    hello

    <div id="circle"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $("#circle").click(function(){

         $("#circle").animate({Width:"400px"}, 2000); 

      });

    </script>

</body>
```

```
#circle{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: green;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: What behavior are you getting?

Comment: IIRC, using css to get the value of a field that is a color will return the value as in rgb() format, not 'red' or 'green'.  It would be easier to do this with a class most likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to go with this approach only- the computed value for the color are represented in RGBa (Red, Blue, Green, Alpha - for opacity) and not in as color names (like red, blue, orange, transparent etc) or as hex values.

```js
$("#greenCircle").click(function() {
  if ($("#greenCircle").css("background-color") == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
    $("#greenCircle").css("background-color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#greenCircle").css("background-color", "red");
  }
});
```

```css
#greenCircle {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenCircle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the css will return the color in rgb format, the use of a class that you can toggle on/off will make this much easier.

```js
$("#greenCircle").click(function() {
  $("#greenCircle").toggleClass('red');
});
```

```css
#greenCircle {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#greenCircle.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenCircle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#greenCircle").css("background-color")` returns the parsed color like `"rgb(0, 128, 0)"`, which isn't equal to `"red"` or `"green"`.

It would be simpler if you used a class to set the color, then you can use `toggleClass()`.

```js
$("#circle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("greenCircle redCircle");
});
```

```css
#circle {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.greenCircle {
  background-color: green;
}
.redCircle {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle" class="greenCircle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The css("background-color") method does not return the actual value in your style attribute but a rgb() value.
Try using console.log to see how the value changes after your change:

```
console.log($("#greenCircle").css("background-color"));
```

Might I suggest a simpler alternative approach:

```
<style>
   #circle {
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   }
   #circle.green{
   background-color: green;
   }
   #circle.red{
   background-color: red;
   }
</style>
<script>
   $("#circle").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red', 'green');
   });
</script>
<div id="circle" class="green"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the code is much cleaner.

```js
$("#greenCircle").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

```css
#greenCircle {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#greenCircle.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greenCircle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was doing an Udemy tutorial and the instructor took this approach. It seemed to work correctly for him. It was just really annoying me. I'll just seek one of the alternatives when I need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

simply add this code and change the IDs to classes

```js
 $(".red").click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('greenCircle red');
 });
```

```css
.greenCircle {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.red {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```HtML
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="red"></div>
```